# vue v-show can't render html by use props property?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```html
<template>
  <div v-show="isShow"></div>
</template>
 <script>
   export default{
      props: {
        isShow: true
      }
   }
 </script>
<test isShow=false></test>
```

this is vue demo.

like this, which can't effect.

why ? why? why?

Answer (score 2):

```
<template>
  <div v-show="isShow"></div>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
    props: {
      isShow: {type: Boolean, default: true }
    }
  }
</script>

<test v-bind:is-show="false"></test>
```